# Match from sequence until a non included optional character or, if not found, until end of line

Tags: regex

I'm searching a way to extract urls from pls, m3u and asx files,

Let's consider this 2 lines string:

```
File=http://stream1:0000
<ref href="http://stream2.xyz"/>
```

I started with `/http\S*/g` to find matches starting with "http" until end of lines, it gives the folowing result:

- `http://stream1:0000`
- `http://stream2.xyz"/>`

So I'm searching a way to add an optional end that would be the `"` character (not included), to be able to have the following result:

- `http://stream1:0000`
- `http://stream2.xyz`

What would be the way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use back-reference

```
(["']|)(http.+)\1
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/lV0jH1/3)

**Regex Explanation:**

1. `(["']|)`: Matches `"` or `'` or nothing
2. `(http.+)`: Matches the string `http` till the end of line or the back-reference and put it in second captured group.
3. `\1`: Backreference. Matches the same thing as in the `(["']|)`. #1

**Note:** I've added single quote with double quote, so this will also work for the URL's wrapped in single quotes. If there are other characters also that can be used to surround the URL, those can be add in the character class.

**To get the URL, use second captured group(*`$2` in most languages/tools*)**

---

**If back-reference/capturing group is not feasible/possible**, you can use following regex

```
http[^'"\n]*
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/lV0jH1/4)

**Regex Explanation:**

`[^'"\n]*` matches anything that is not `'`, `"` or newline as many times as possible.

[image: Regex Visualization]

Comment: Thank you, it works good except that I would like to excude the " character from the result

Comment: @jck For that you need to use result of second capture group. In most languages it is `$2`. Which language/tool you're using?

Comment: @jck I've added another way at the bottom of answer. Check if this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Following regex should work:

(http[^\s"]*)[\s"]

https://regex101.com/r/xC4qV4/1